# Why doesn't my script make a div show/hide based on a dropdown selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm definitely a JS/jquery newbie. I'm using Wordpress and Woocommerce for a site. When viewing a specific product, if a user selects "custom" for their size, I want the price (and add to cart, but I haven't gotten to that point yet) to hide. I got the following code from similar posts, but it doesn't work:

When I select custom in runtime, nothing happens. What am I doing incorrectly? Thank you!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#pa_size").on('change', function() {
    if (this.value == 'custom') {
      $('.price').hide();
    } else {
      $('.price').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.js'></script>
<table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="label"><label for="pa_size">Size</label></td>
      <td class="value">
        <select id="pa_size" class="" name="attribute_pa_size" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_size" data-show_option_none="yes">
          <option value="">Choose an option</option>
          <option value="78" class="attached enabled">78"</option>
          <option value="custom" class="attached enabled">Custom</option>
        </select>
        <a class="reset_variations" href="#" style="visibility: visible; display: inline;">Clear</a> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="single_variation_wrap">
  <div class="woocommerce-variation single_variation" style="display: block;">
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-description">
      <p>Need a custom size? Contact us for a quote!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-price"><span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>0.00</bdi>
      </span>
      </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: This isn't valid JavaScript: `$( this.value == 'custom')` Did you forget to include an `if()` statement?

Comment: You can also check for any other javascript errors by using dev tools of Chrome.

Comment: It is valid, but I'm not sure what would jQuery find with a boolean.

Comment: Updated it to reflect that I have - don't know what happened to my "if" as it really is in the code I have.

Comment: Try debugging with devtools first, before posting this.

Comment: The code you have shown works absolutely fine. Please check the console in your local version for errors.

Comment: This is what I have, no errors in dev tools. Still not working.

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#pa_size").on('change', function() {
      if( this.value == 'custom') 
      {
        $('.price').hide();
      }
      else
      {
        $('.price').show();
      }
    });

});

Comment: Like @Rory McCrossan said. The Code Snippet you have presented here works fine. The only thing I could think of is that usually you would validate a *character* like `if ( this.value === "custom" )`

Comment: Thank you for taking a look! Not sure what's happening, but at least my code is correct!

Comment: Just for the record, I am confirming that the code snippet works as posted.